# Is there a way inn Excel to capture the value of a cell at a certain time in regular intervals?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a shipping dashboard I'm working on, and I'm trying to find a way to record an hourly log of the value of shipped goods every hour, and make a live line graph based on it?

[image]

Starting on the left, I have a power query table which pulls data off a server every 5 minutes. The "today?" column checks if the ship date matches today's date, and filters out goods that were shipped yesterday, so you're only seeing goods that were shipped today.

In the blue pivot table on the right, I have combined ship value - the pivot table shows todays current shipped value (£178,924.81), and the past days combined total, as far back as the report goes. This one can be ignored.

To the right of this, I have a value which represents todays target. This is manually entered, and split between the 17 hours that the company is open for. Each hour, the target accumulates, so that by the time we reach hour 17, the target should be £525,000.00.

Towards the bottom, I have the current time, which is updated every minute.

I want to be able to compare the current time to the time in the table, and if the hour matches, display a "snapshot" of the shipped value in the accumulate column. Alternatively, I would like to take a snapshot of the shipped value at the turn of each hour, and populate each row accordingly, so that we have a log of how much we shipped each hour, and compare with each hours target.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: TBH, given what you've made the query do already, I'd have thought getting a snapshot would be relatively trivial...?  May help guide you to comparing the hours: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/date-time.html

Comment: So what you're suggesting is, I just copy the shipped value to each accumulate cell?

Comment: If the shipped value is only per hour, then I expect you'll want to add what has been done  earlier in the day? (Or if the shipped value is that of the day so far, then yeah, I guess straight copy.) But really thats up to how *you* want to display it - using DateValue() should give you a good means of getting your snapshot when you want to

Comment: @Amiga500, the Shipped value is for the entire day, so a straight copy. I've made some progress. I'm using the line "Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H26").Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K8")" to copy the shipped value into the table. However, when the shipped value updates itself, the value in the table also updates. However, the value in the table should remain FIXED. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you copy/pasting as a formula or as a value?

Comment: The shipped value is a formula which references the cell in the pivot table, which totals the power query. But I just want to copy the value at a specific time.

Comment: .pastespecial values should do the trick I'd think, look here: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/value-paste-pastespecial/